# UI with Transparent Background doesn't show the Next Immediate Layer

Tags: c#, winforms, background, transparent

If we set the background of any UI as transparent, it doesn't show what's beneath that, meaning any UI or containers.  Instead, it shows the default background of the Form, the lowermost, that is.

How do I get around this transparency problem?

Comment: They are transparent against their Parent.  Which is the form.  If you want them to be transparent against some other control then change the Parent property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, unfortunately:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943454

> Transparent controls in WinForms are transparent relative to their
>   parent, not to other controls. Transparency in WinForms is more akin
>   to camouflage than true transparency. A transparent control doesn’t
>   actually let you see the control behind it through the form. It asks
>   its parent to draw its own background on the "transparent" control.
>   This is why a transparent control shows the form behind it, but covers
>   up any other controls.

There is some code in the link that demonstrates a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent.

To give your control a transparent backcolor
This will enable your control to support a transparent backcolor.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```